# Trained model is empty after fitting

Tags: ml.net

I'm trying to implement a simple linear regression with ML.NET. I have followed Microsoft's tutorial, except that I'm loading data from an IEnumerable rather than from a file. However, I always get zero as a prediction. Investigating back, I found that the model's parameters are empty (see screenshot below).

This is the simplest program with which I was able to reproduce the problem.

```
class Data
{
    public float Revenue { get; set; }
    public float Customers { get; set; }
    public float IsWeekend { get; set; }
}

class DataPrediction
{ 
    [ColumnName("Score")]
    public float RevenueEstimate { get; set; }
}

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Data> trainData = new List<Data>();
    trainData.Add(new Data { IsWeekend = 0, Customers = 20, Revenue = 138 });
    trainData.Add(new Data { IsWeekend = 0, Customers = 18, Revenue = 106 });
    trainData.Add(new Data { IsWeekend = 0, Customers = 26, Revenue = 142 });
    trainData.Add(new Data { IsWeekend = 0, Customers = 21, Revenue = 131 });
    trainData.Add(new Data { IsWeekend = 0, Customers = 33, Revenue = 146 });
    trainData.Add(new Data { IsWeekend = 1, Customers = 92, Revenue = 287 });
    trainData.Add(new Data { IsWeekend = 1, Customers = 113, Revenue = 312 });

    List<Data> testData = new List<Data>();
    testData.Add(new Data { IsWeekend = 0, Customers = 27, Revenue = 136 });
    testData.Add(new Data { IsWeekend = 0, Customers = 22, Revenue = 109 });
    testData.Add(new Data { IsWeekend = 1, Customers = 87, Revenue = 256 });

    MLContext mlContext = new MLContext();
    IDataView trainDataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(trainData);
    IDataView testDataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(testData);

    var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.CopyColumns("Label", "Revenue")
        .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "Customers", "IsWeekend"))
        .Append(mlContext.Regression.Trainers.FastTree())
        ;
    var model = pipeline.Fit(trainDataView);

    var predictions = model.Transform(testDataView);
    var metrics = mlContext.Regression.Evaluate(predictions, "Label", "Score");

    var predictionFunction = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<Data, DataPrediction>(model);
    var prediction = predictionFunction.Predict(new Data { IsWeekend = 1, Customers = 108 });
}
```

Here is what I get if I break at the closing brace:

[image]

Of course, `prediction.RevenueEstimate` is 0, and the metrics show an average absolute error and a RMS error that are similar to the label's average.

It seems to me that this is a very essential program, and I'm using the FastTree LR trainer just like Microsoft suggests in its tutorial. What am I doing wrong?

PS: Decorating the data classes with `ColumnName` attributes has no effect.

Comment: It's probably due to there being so little data to train on. Try adding more data to see if that helps.

Comment: @Jon You are right. Is there a guideline about how many samples are needed? What trainer should I consider if I have small quantities of samples (I'd guess OnlineGradientDescent could work)?